# How can I debug an bmac project in omnet?

Tags: c++, omnet++

How can I debug an omnet++ project like as a bmac or Imac.
My omnet++ is Version: 4.6 I want to debug an bmac project. Do I need to change any configuration of my simulator?
I will be thank full to have the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat broad. If, by *debugging* a simulation you mean running your simulation in a debugger like `gdb`, see [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30298110/4707703).

For general tips on *debugging* in the sense of finding errors, you might find [this article on the OMNeT++ wiki helpful](https://omnetpp.org/pmwiki/index.php?n=Main.CplusplusDebuggingTips).